# How to remove webpart title hyperlink

Tags: web-part

Can you please assist me for removing hyperlink from webpart title. I have added # in webpart URL option but I want to make the webpart title non-clickable.

Comment: what version of sharepoint are you using?

Answer (score 10):

1. Edit page
2. Edit web part
3. Appearance --> Advanced --> Title URL
4. Remove value of field
5. Save

If that doesn't do it:

- place a "#" in the Title URL field

If still that is not good enough:

- place "###" in the Title URL field and

---

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

       $('a').filter("[href='###']").each(function () {
        $(this).replaceWith($(this).html());
       });

 });
```

Comment: We had to use %23%23%23 instead of ### in jQuery to get it working